# If-$/true=$ - assistance needed with field formula

Tags: column, calculated-column-formula, property

I am tracking a list on sharepoint and want to use this to reconcile the invoice.  I have a field named "Appraisal Type" that has two choices.  If one of them is chosen (MVProRE Exterior)I want another field "Invoice Amount" to auto-fill at $195.00.

I have been playing with the value box on the Field/Group Properties and keep getting errors.  My brain tells me to do this but keep getting an error.  Any assistance is appreciated.

```
IF(AppraisalType=MVProRE Exterior)="$195.00"
```

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work.  I am working in the Field or Group Properties box in InfoPath - Microsoft InfoPath states the formula contains one or more errors.  When I "show details" it states, "Expected Value Type:  ,  Then shows:  Actual Value: name  IF(../my:AppraisalType=MVProRE-->Exterior<--)="195.00"

Comment: Try `IF(AppraisalType=MVProRE Exterior) InvoiceAmount="$195.00"`. The expected value type error is probably happening because you are trying to assign a value of the wrong type to something.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax for the calculated column is slightly wrong. The correct syntax is of the form

```
=IF([column]=value,"trueValue","FalseValue")
```

There are examples and more [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb862071(v=office.14).aspx). So you would want to do somehting like this.

```
=IF(AppraisalType=MVProRE Exterior, "$195.00", "FalseValue")
```

Hope this helps, and if you have any more questions just post a comment and Ill see if I can help.

Comment: This is just not working for me in InfoPath - I keep getting the same errors.  I have checked multiple times and have had others look at it - we are following along your correction but SharePoint won't do it.  :-(  Other ideas?